# Admob both test ads and real ads are not showing

Tags: swift, admob

My app is not receiving neither of the Test ads or Real ads from Admob in both simulator and real device. But if I change the bundle id of the app, it receives both type of ads just fine. The issue is coming up after I switched the app to new AdMob account. I have updated the publisher id in Info.plist file and also the ad units that are being used to that of new account.

The error received is:

```
Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.}
```

I have implemented the Admob following guides at

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner

```
var bannerView: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self

    bannerView.delegate = self

    bannerView.load(GADRequest())

    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
}

func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
      [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                          attribute: .bottom,
                          relatedBy: .equal,
                          toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                          attribute: .top,
                          multiplier: 1,
                          constant: 0),
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                          attribute: .centerX,
                          relatedBy: .equal,
                          toItem: view,
                          attribute: .centerX,
                          multiplier: 1,
                          constant: 0)
      ])
   }
...

func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {

    print(error)
}
```

Comment: where did you add the `bannerView` to `viewController`'s `view`. And please check your `adUnitID`

Comment: I have added the relevant code to add the banner view. The ad unit is test ad unit `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716`

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I can get real ads to show, and I can get test ads to show. 

Their documentation is outdated? Their provided banner demo ad unit ID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716) does not work. Via https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads